# Field value not updating when posting data via JSON for date field

Tags: php, json, rest

**Drupal 7**

Here I am getting 200 response but the **date field** over here is not getting updated.using service module

iam using **date-- popup calendar** in content type

```
"field_date_of_age": {
        "und": [
            {
                "date": "2018-04-01",
                "time": "00:00:00",
                "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
                "timezone_db": "Asia/Kolkata"

            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: What is your question please?

Comment: @Syscall i am updating a content type via services module .. apart from "date field"  rest of all field is getting updated.

Comment: @Syscall is there any clarification required

Comment: what code performs the update?